# Laravel 5.3 filter search data in API

Tags: php, laravel, api, search, laravel-5.3

I'm implementing an API for `front end and mobile apps` now i'm working on `search function` where a user may type `column name` or any `data` i should be able to provide the data they request in a JSON format

so for i did this

in my controller

```
public function getSearchResults(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->get('data');

    $search_drivers = Driver::where('agent_id', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('registration_center', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('registration_id', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('sponsor_name', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('event_name', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('registration_id', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('profile_photo', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%{$data}%")
                     ->get();

    return Response::json([
        'data' => $search_drivers
    ]);     
}
```

on searching with parameter i'm getting the JSON response as

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search?data=center 

//Response
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "agent_id": "201701",
            "registration_center": "Center",
            "registration_date": "12-01-2017",
            "sponsor_name": "Sponser Name",
            "event_name": "Event Name",
            "registration_id": "45345343543353",
            "profile_photo": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
          }
    ]
}
```

but how do i filter the json something like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search?data=center 

//Response
{
    "data": [
        {
            "registration_center": "center",
          }
    ]
}
```

is it possible to do that, could you please tell me or give me some example how to `query and return as json`

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `['registration_center']` to `get()`:

```
->get(['registration_center']);
```

Or use `select()` before `get()`:

```
->select('registration_center')
->get();
```

Comment: could you please tell me how the query should be in case of multiple tables, i mean join multiple tables and query

Comment: Use `select()` when you'll use joins. You can see an example of using `select()` with `join()` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins).

Comment: thanks for the docs, is there a better way to implement search in `API`, this API is for `mobile apps` when they enter a keyword i should be able to give all the data in the database with that keyword just like `google search auto complete`

Comment: @MrRobot I guess your solution is ok for many cases. You may also want to read about [Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout), [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co) and similar solutions.